# RODBC not returning results when calling nested stored procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, stored-procedures, rodbc

I have a nested MySQL stored procedure that's basically structured like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_main`(in param1 int, in param2 int)
BEGIN
declare refid int;
# do some stuff here
select refid;
call sp_child(param1, param2, refid);
END
```

Both sp_main and sp_child are stored procedures, the problem is sp_child itself has a return value (call it `refid2`) and when I use sqlquery in RODBC I always ended up getting `refid2` instead of `refid` (which is what I need), although when I run it in MySQL Workbench I ended up seeing both `refid` and `refid2` when `call sp_main(...)`. All sp_child param are "in" params and the only "out" value is returned in the end of sp_child call.

Is there any way I could either:

Change the code in sp_main so that the output in sp_child is does not gets shown? I tried to use `set @output = call sp_child(...);` to suppress the output showing up when calling sp_main but that ended up giving me a syntax error. The sp_child unfortunately can not be modified as it is shared with several other SPs and changing the params would require changing all of the dependent SPs. Also obviously making sp_child to become a function is also out of question.

OR

Somehow use sqlquery in RODBC (or another R package or function) to somehow get both the output from the sp_child call AND sp_main call?

Thanks!

Comment: If procedure sends the data into the output stream (executes SELECT) more than once (in single procedure or in upper and nested procedures) then your program receives a collection of rowsets. To obtain all data selected you must iterate this collection and fetch each rowset in it.

Comment: @Akina - the "main" sp has only one select but there is another select in "child" SP which is called by the main. Also from this thread (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-March/466123.html) it doesn't seem there is a way to get multiple outputs out of sqlQuery, any other R package/function you'd recommend? I see some were using COM objects but that only works in Windows. :(